# Proper use of the following functions:describeBy, statsBy, and stat.desc

Tags: r

I am using R 3.2.0 and have been successful using the `aggregate` function but it gives minimum statistics, `tapply` gives more than the aggregate function but the summary statistics are limited. For the following data with 4 groups of different n’s can anyone show me how to use following functions properly: `describeBy`, `statsBy`, and `stat.desc`? Following is the data and incorrect syntax for the above functions that I used.

```
data <- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66, 68, 66, 71, 67, 68, 68, 56, 62, 60, 61, 63, 64, 63, 59)
grp <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(4,6,6,8)))
df <- data.frame(group=grp, dt=data)
describeBy(data, df$dt, df$group, mean,median,min,max,sd)
statsBy(df,mean,median,min,max,sd)
stat.desc(df,basic=F)
```

Comment: From which package(s) are `describeBy`, `statsBy`, and `stat.desc` coming?

Comment: @Pascal - `psych` I think

Comment: @thelatemail Probably, but it is the job of the OP to provide such details.

Comment: `aggregate` can deliver any statistic you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(DescTools)  # not asked for, but better
Desc(df, plot = T)

library(psych)
describeBy(df, df$group)
# statsBy tries to find correlations, but you have only 1 numerical variable here.

library(doBy)
library(pastecs)
summaryBy(dt ~ group, data = df, FUN = stat.desc)
```